# R refer to multiple dataframe columns to exclude data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data frame that I am working with from which I need to exclude rows that contain all but a small number of characters.

Currently I am using the following code to do so and it is working fine, but I can only seem to apply this to a single column at a time which is not only inefficient but time consuming on my part as I have many columns to work through.

```
df <- df[(df$column_name_01 %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d")),]
```

So far I have tried referring to multiple columns like so (as this approach works for single columns):

```
df <- df[(df[, 1:10] %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d")),]
```

But this is obviously not working as intended. Is there a concise way to exclude rows from a data frame that contain certain characters (or that do not match certain characters, either way)?

Comment: You may need `lapply` ie. `lapply(df[1:10, function (x) x[x %in% c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a regular old apply here:

```
df[apply(df[,1:10], 1, function(x) all(x %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"))),]
```

Or for non-matching rows

```
df[apply(df[,1:10], 1, function(x) all(! x %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"))),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute whether you want each row across the 10 columns, combining into a single vector with `Reduce` and `"&"`:

```
df[Reduce("&", lapply(df[,1:10], function(x) x %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"))),]
#    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 14  a  c  a  d  d  c  d  c  c  c
# 25  b  a  a  a  b  a  c  a  a  c
# 29  d  d  d  a  a  a  b  c  c  a
# 31  c  b  b  d  b  c  a  b  b  c
# 33  b  a  c  b  a  d  c  a  a  c
# 36  c  d  c  b  d  a  c  a  a  a
# 42  b  b  a  a  b  c  d  b  d  d
# 45  c  c  b  b  d  a  b  a  d  b
```

You could also do this by converting the data frame to a matrix and using `rowSums` to make sure all values in the row fall in the desired set:

```
df[rowSums(matrix(unlist(df[,1:10]) %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow(df))) == 10,]
#    NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 14  a  c  a  d  d  c  d  c  c  c
# 25  b  a  a  a  b  a  c  a  a  c
# 29  d  d  d  a  a  a  b  c  c  a
# 31  c  b  b  d  b  c  a  b  b  c
# 33  b  a  c  b  a  d  c  a  a  c
# 36  c  d  c  b  d  a  c  a  a  a
# 42  b  b  a  a  b  c  d  b  d  d
# 45  c  c  b  b  d  a  b  a  d  b
```

Both of these solutions should be faster than an `apply`-based solution for large matrices (I benchmark a 100k-row data frame here) because they operate on a small number of columns instead of a large number of rows, better taking advantage of vectorization:

```
josilber.lapply <- function(df) df[Reduce("&", lapply(df[,1:10], function(x) x %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"))),]
josilber.rowSums <- function(df) df[rowSums(matrix(unlist(df[,1:10]) %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow(df))) == 10,]
crimson.apply <- function(df) df[apply(df[,1:10], 1, function(x) all(x %in% c("a", "b", "c", "d"))),]
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(josilber.lapply(big.df), josilber.rowSums(big.df), crimson.apply(big.df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                      expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   josilber.lapply(big.df)  67.17092  71.0628  83.36787  74.74011  86.00722  231.6794   100
#  josilber.rowSums(big.df)  98.75142 116.3975 136.28880 128.28851 149.55155  301.9346   100
#     crimson.apply(big.df) 676.66290 725.6616 789.45954 762.74171 805.72437 2681.8203   100
```

Data:

```
set.seed(144)
df <- unname(do.call(data.frame, replicate(10, sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace=TRUE), simplify=FALSE)))
set.seed(144)
big.df <- unname(do.call(data.frame, replicate(10, sample(letters[1:5], 100000, replace=TRUE), simplify=FALSE)))
```